# jQuery – select the first element only

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How does one select an element ONLY if it's the first element within another element? In the examples below, I want to select and apply a margin-top of 0 if the h3 is ONLY the first element.

I thought this would work:

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container h3').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':first-of-type') ) {
        $(this).css('margin-top','0');
    }
});
```

But this selects the first h3 in the div. So then I tried:

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container h3').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':first') ) {
        $(this).css('margin-top','0');
    }
});
```

But this doesn't seem to select anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container h3:first').css('margin-top','0');` - Use this

Comment: @rdck this depends on your html markup, would you mind posting that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container h3:first-child').css('margin-top','0');
```

This will select a descendant h3 of `.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container` which is the first child element of a parent

Comment: Did you mean to replace `:first-of-type` with `:first-child` instead? Checking for type after child seems redundant.

Comment: @BoltClock forgot to check what was happening in the each loop,... that itself is not required

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container h3:first-child').css('margin-top','0');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple solutions , but i will correct yours :

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container h3').each(
 function(index , value) {
    if ( index == 0 ) {//if it's the first element
        $(this).css('margin-top','0');
    }
});
```

Other solutions:

1. [:first Selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)
2. [:nth-child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[: first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** selector

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container h3:first').css('margin-top','0');
```

or **[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)**

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container h3').first().css('margin-top','0');
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z2pK/)**

---

If you have multiple `.text-container` classes,

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container').each(function(){
    $(this).find('h3:first').css('margin-top','0').css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: what i posted, have you seen it? in your comment lines.

Comment: Right, in case of that hierarchy +1.

Comment: what i mean is what if there are multiple `.text-containers`??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container').each(function(i) {
    if (i === 0) {
       $('h3', this).css('margin-top','0');
    }
});
```

or:

```
$('.flexible-content-container .each-flexible-section .text-container').each(function(i) {

       $('h3:first', this).css('margin-top','0');

});
```